# Error in Netlogo code once I turn on my boolean variable. Does anyone see the error?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to develop an agent-based model of a Rock-Paper-Scissors game but want to know how this dynamic shifts once spatial interactions are turned on (spatial-interactions? is my boolean variable). The model runs fine when the boolean switch is turned off however, once I turn it on, NetLogo throws out an error (pasted below). There seems to be an error in the play-game procedure but the error is not obvious to me. I suspect that I am not using the netlogo primitive "with" correctly but I have looked at many examples and I dont see the problem with how I have it written in the code.  Any help y'all can provide would be appreciated! I have also pasted the code below.

*WITH expected input to be an agentset but got NOBODY instead.
error while turtle 8 running WITH
called by procedure PLAY-GAME
called by procedure GO
called by Button 'go'*

```
to play-game
  let orange-morphs count co-players with [strategy = "orange"]
  let yellow-morphs count co-players with [strategy = "yellow" ]
  let blue-morphs count co-players with [strategy = "blue" ]

  if strategy = "orange" [
    set payoff payoff + (0 * yellow-morphs) + (1 * orange-morphs) + (win-payoff * blue-morphs)
  ]

  if strategy = "yellow" [
    set payoff payoff + (1 * yellow-morphs) + (win-payoff * orange-morphs) + (0 * blue-morphs)
  ]

  if strategy = "blue" [
    set payoff payoff + (win-payoff * yellow-morphs) + (0 * orange-morphs) + (1 * blue-morphs)
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With your spatial dynamics, I assume that you get cases when your agents are not close enough to any other agents so that they have nobody to play against. This error happens when there are no agents grouped in the agentset `co-players`.

You can circumvent this by adding `if (any? co-players) [ ... ]` at the start of this procedure, with the entire rest of the procedure within the square brackets. That causes them not to try playing if there is nobody around to play with.

Comment: Thank you for responding to this post so quickly! I tried your suggestion and I got an error but I made sure the ```set co-players to turtles-on neighbors``` which is weird though because in my go procedure I already set my co-players. I received another error but in my reproduce procedure now. Supposedly, I did not input a turtle agentset.

Comment: This is the error message _OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle but got NOBODY instead.
error while turtle 9 running OF
  called by procedure REPRODUCE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'_  I dont know why the error is only popping up when I have my spatial-interaction? turned on. Do you notice an error in my code?                       ```to reproduce
  let most-fit max-one-of co-players [payoff]
  if ([payoff] of most-fit) > payoff[
    set strategy ([strategy] of most-fit)
  ]
end```

Comment: P.s. I am very new to coding and agent-based modeling so I may have some rookie mistakes.

Comment: @bsalazar7 It would be helpful if you edit your original question and just psate your entire code in it. The problem here is exactly the same as the one I described in my answer: "Sometimes there is a turtle with no co-players which gives you an error".